# Angular constant vs javascript constant

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose that I have a global constant that need to be accessible in every angular module, what is the advisable approach to declare the constant. I have three approach in my mind but i not sure which to be used.

**Appreciate if anyone could point out what is the benefit using Approach 2 compare to Approach 1 in this condition.**

Approach 1 (pure js constant):

```
var jsConstant = {
    constant1: 'constant1',
    constant2: 'constant2'
};

angular.module('mainApp').controller(['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.constant1 = jsConstant.constant1;
    $scope.constant2 = jsConstant.constant2;
}]);
```

Approach 2 (pure angular constant)

```
angular.module('mainApp').constant('angularConstant', {
    'constant1': 'constant1',
    'constant2': 'constant2'
});


angular.module('mainApp').controller(['myConstant', '$scope', function(myConstant, $scope) {
    $scope.constant1 = angularConstant.constant1;
    $scope.constant2 = angularConstant.constant2;
}]);
```

Approach 3 (mixture of js and angular constant)

```
var jsConstant = {
    constant1: 'constant1',
    constant2: 'constant2'
};

angular.module('mainApp').constant('angularConstant", {
    'constant1': jsConstant.constant1;
    'constant2': jsConstant.constant2;
});


angular.module('mainApp').controller(['myConstant', '$scope', function(myConstant, $scope) {
    $scope.constant1 = angularConstant.constant1;
    $scope.constant2 = angularConstant.constant2;
}]);
```

Comment: 1 and 2 are identical

Comment: You may create a service and inject it. Let the service return the constant.

Comment: @zerkms i have change the code for 2

Comment: Exist a angular way. `angular.module('myApp').constant('Cons',{})`. And then you may do injection in your controllers. And yo can create separate file with constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advisable way is to use `constant`:

```js
(function(angular, undefined) {
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.constants', [])

.constant('appConfig', {userRoles:['guest','user','admin']});

})(angular);
```

Even better way is to inject those values on every build from the server, since most of the time you want to define those values on your server and forget about managing them in other places. For that purpose take a look at `ng-constant` module for `grunt` or `gulp`

**Edit**
Approach 3 is just a messy version of Approach 2 with unnecessary declaration of JS variables outside of Angular modules

Approach 1 is not good, because you those constants are not really reusable. If you have another controller that wants to reuse those values?

Comment: I am confuse. what do you mean by constant in approach 1 is not reusable? it seems to me that approach 1 javascript constant can be reuse in each and every controller with following way: var jsConstant is in another js file and the js file is loaded in master layout

Comment: Loaded preceeding angular app? What if there is another module reusing/modifying those variables?

Answer (score 0):

In approach 1 you created a global variable `jsConstants` which, I believe, is not treated as a good practice - you should avoid creating global constants if possible. Moreover - properties of `jsConstants` are not really constant - anyone, anywhere can change them. Also, using global constant makes controllers less testable (unit), as they will depend on this global object.

In approach 2 I believe you are not allowed to change these values, so they more act as constant values. You inject them in controllers, so they are still unit-testable.